# Date picker returning dateTime with time zone in VueJS Element Library

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using date picker from http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/date-picker

It should return date in form:

> yyyy-MM-dd

However, it is returning like:

> Thu Apr 20 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

This is the code that I've used

```
<el-date-picker 
v-model="date" 
type="date" 
placeholder="Pick a day" 
format="yyyy-MM-dd">
</el-date-picker>
```

Comment: Can you make a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `computed property` or `filter` to get the desired output.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/33/

```
<div id="app">
  <el-date-picker 
  v-model="date" 
  type="date" 
  placeholder="Pick a day" 
  format="yyyy-MM-dd">
  </el-date-picker>
  <p v-if="date">{{ dateFormat }}</p>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    date: null
  },
  computed: {
    dateFormat: function() {
        let date = new Date(this.date);
        return date.getFullYear() + '-' + 
          (date.getMonth() +1) + '-' + 
          date.getDate();  
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me check it

Comment: Have you noticed one thing, the month is decremented by one. Everytime. Any fix for that?

Comment: This is how JS Date behaves. Check the answer again, it's updated to fix this issue.

Comment: Got it. But why is these like these. This is because of JavaScript or VueJS?

Comment: @GijoVarghese what exactly? Date.getMonth() return month index startting from 0, this is JS native behavior: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth